# iRola DX752 does not charge after a while

Tags: charging

The iRola DX752 purchased for Christmas does not charge. It worked for a while, but then does not work when plugged to an outlet either.

Is this a known hardware failure? If it isn't, are there any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure any of your fellow users will be able to help you with that. It sounds like you need to take it back to the shop.

Comment: [You're not the first person to have trouble with this model of tablet.](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/60228/my-irola-dx752-will-not-turn-on)

Comment: Have you tried different cables? Different charging methods, like USB versus wall charger? Does anything happen when you plug it in? Any pop-ups when connecting it via USB to your computer? If all turns out negative, I'm afraid you've got to follow Dan's above advice.

Answer (score 0):

This was my Christmas present to myself also.  It only charges with the 2.5mm plug on the AC Adaptor that was supplied with the tablet.  The mini-USB port and the supplied cable works well with transferring data, but cannot be used for charging.  I've tried different mini-USB cables, different AC wall plugs, but the mini-USB will not provide a charge.  At least the supplied AC charger works, but if it ever breaks, good luck in finding a replacement, as the Chinese manufacturer is hard to reach.

I have seen a car-charger adaptor kit from Radio Shack for $20, that will do the job from your car's cigarette lighter port.  Those are the only two options I've found so far.

Answer (score 0):

I also bought 2 DX752 tablets which displayed similar symptoms. It seems to be a hardware fault, and you should have it replaced by the manufacturer. Here's the contact information provided to me via Kocaso.com:

> Global Phoenix Computers T&S
>   Phone #s (607)257-7279 or (866)777-0069

They responded by asking for my receipt and then they will send me a replacement.